# Bootstrap datepicker "next" arrow is disabled for month selection view

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a date picker where I have setted an end date to it. The end date is within the current year (2020). But When I am in the "month" selection view, the "next" arrow from 2019 to 2020 is disabled, like this

[image]

But I do have some options for the year 2020. For example default view mode works just fine, I can navigate in and out from 2020. In the default view mode I can see this:

[image]

My date picker setup look like this:

```
    initDatePickers: function() {
    var format = eco3.getDatePickerFormatValue();
    $(".date-from-filter , #date-from").datepicker({
        format: format,
        endDate: '+0d',
        weekStart: 0,
        autoclose: true
    }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
        $('#date-to').datepicker('setStartDate', e.date);
    });

    $(".date-to-filter , #date-to ").datepicker({
        format: format,
        endDate: '+0d',
        weekStart: 0,
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: $('#date-from').datepicker('getDate')
    });
},
```

So, do you guys have any idea on how to make this next arrow appear whem navigating from 2019 to 2020?

Edit: https://codepen.io/ricardomachadosb/pen/OJMvjbp

Comment: When you select 2020 on **.date-from-filter** picker, then are you able to get 2020 on **.date-to-filter** picker?

Comment: Yes I can see that if I click on 2020. But if I click on the prev arrow, I go to 2019 and I can't see the next arrow.

Edit: Sorry, I missundertood the question. I am always able to get 2020 in the date to filter independent of the date-from value. 

The only problem is when I am on the "month" view in the date to. If I leave the 2020 window, I can't go back to it using the arrows.

Comment: One more thing I want to confirm, when you use **+0d**, does it set the date according to the startDate's relative date or relative to current date (today)?

Comment: It's relative to the current date.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a pen?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "create a pen".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217361/discussion-between-tushar-and-ricardo-machado).

Comment: https://codepen.io/ricardomachadosb/pen/OJMvjbp